Matlab Appdesigner Simulink Simulation endless loop
I was assigned an existing app project. There i should implement a Simulink model for a dead beat controller. The Simulink model works for every input i give, but only when doing it with my test file.
In the main file give the transfer function Gs to the model, the tau value, the value of u_min and u_max. The controller should get the variables, regulate it and give me back the u, corrected w and corrected e. But the simulation gets into a loop and i cant do anything. It crashes right wenn i do :
simOut = sim('Deadbeatregler.slx','SimulationMode','normal');

It worked for sometime. Dont remember changing anything.
I will show the app designer code for my recall function. The other codes i put in a pastebin link.
Callback Function:
% Button pushed function: StartButton
        function StartButtonPushed(app, event)
        
        %Löschen aller Text- und Diagramm-Inhalte
            app.StreckeTextArea.Value = '';
            app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = '';
            app.MesswerteTable.Data = {};
            cla(app.RegelAxes);
            cla(app.StellAxes);

        %Streckenübertragungsfunktion in die Funktion holen    
            Gs = evalin('base','Gs');

        %Entscheidung, welche Strategie gewählt wird
        % IT2_Strecke = 0 -> PT2 oder IT2_Strecke = 1 -> IT2
            
            %Teststrecke
            %IT2_Strecke = 0;
            %PT2 = tf(3, [0.1 0.7 1]);              
            %IT2 = tf(10, [0.02 0.3 1 0]);


            %Eingabewerte auslesen und übergeben
            assignin('base','u_max',app.U_maxEditField.Value);
            assignin('base','u_min',app.U_minEditField.Value);
            assignin('base','tau',app.AbtastzeitEditField.Value);
            %assignin('base','IT2',0);
            IT2_Strecke = evalin('base','IT2_Strecke');
            %auswahlModi = app.RegelstrategieButtonGroup.Text;
            u_max = evalin('base','u_max');
            u_min = evalin('base','u_min');
            if IT2_Strecke < 1
            
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % PT2-Strecke %
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            
                %gs = PT2;
                tau = evalin('base', 'tau');
                gz = c2d(Gs, tau); % kontinuierliche Strecke diskretisieren     
            
                [numerator, denominator] = tfdata(gz);  % Koeffizienten der diskretiesierten Strecke extrahieren
            
                % Zähler
                b2 = numerator{1}(1); 
                b1 = numerator{1}(2); 
                b0 = numerator{1}(3); % niedrigster Exponent
            
                % Nenner
                a2 = denominator{1}(1);
                a1 = denominator{1}(2); 
                a0 = denominator{1}(3); % niedrigster Exponent
               
                assignin('base','b2',b2);
                assignin('base','b1',b2);
                assignin('base','b0',b0);

                assignin('base','a2',a2);
                assignin('base','a1',a1);
                assignin('base','a0',a0);

            else
            
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            % IT2-Strecke %
            %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
            
                %gs = IT2;
                tau = evalin('base', 'tau');
                gz = c2d(Gs, tau); % kontinuierliche Strecke diskretisieren     
            
                [numerator, denominator] = tfdata(gz); % Koeffizienten der diskretiesierten Strecke extrahieren
            
                % Zähler
                b2 = numerator{1}(2); 
                b1 = numerator{1}(3); 
                b0 = numerator{1}(4); % niedrigster Exponent
            
                % Nenner
                a2 = denominator{1}(2); 
                a1 = denominator{1}(3);
                a0 = denominator{1}(4); % niedrigster Exponent
            
                assignin('base','b2',b2);
                assignin('base','b1',b2);
                assignin('base','b0',b0);

                assignin('base','a2',a2);
                assignin('base','a1',a1);
                assignin('base','a0',a0);

            end


            %Debug
            %gs = evalin('base', 'gs');
            %app.DebugTextArea.Value = gs;
            


            %Werte aus Simulation holen
            simOut = sim('Deadbeatregler.slx','SimulationMode','normal');
            Sollwert_korr_w = simOut.get('Sollwert_korr_w');          
            Sollwert_korr_e = simOut.get('Sollwert_korr_e');            
            Sollwert_korr_u = simOut.get('Sollwert_korr_u');
            Sollwert_Regelgroesse = simOut.get('Sollwert_Regelgroesse');
            Sollwert_Stellgroesse = simOut.get('Sollwert_Stellgroesse');
            Abtastzeit_Regelgroesse = simOut.get('Abtastzeit_Regelgroesse');
            Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse = simOut.get('Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse');
            
            %Debug
            assignin('base',"Sollwert_Stellgroesse",Sollwert_Stellgroesse);
            assignin('base',"Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse",Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse);
            assignin('base',"Sollwert_korr_u",Sollwert_korr_u);
            assignin('base',"Sollwert_korr_w",Sollwert_korr_w);
            assignin('base',"Sollwert_korr_e",Sollwert_korr_e);

            if IT2_Strecke < 1
            % Ausgabe der Streckenübertragungsfunktion Gz
                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = sprintf('\t%.5fz + %.5f\nGz(z) =  ―――――――――――――――――― \n\t%.5fz² + %.5fz',b2,b1,a2,a1);

            % Ausgabe des Dead-Beat-Reglers Gz
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = sprintf('\tz² + %.5fz + %.5f\nGr(z) =  ―――――――――――――――――――――― \n\t%.5fz³ + %.5fz² + %.5fz',a1,a2,b1+b2,-b1,-b2);
            else
            % Ausgabe der Streckenübertragungsfunktion Gz
                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = sprintf('\t%.5fz² + %.5fz + %.5f\nGz(z) =  ―――――――――――――――――― \n\tz³ + %.5fz² + %.5fz + %.5f',b1,b2,b3,a1,a2,a3);

            % Ausgabe des Dead-Beat-Reglers Gz
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = sprintf('\tz³ + %.5fz² + %.5fz + %.5f\nGr(z) =  ―――――――――――――――――――――― \n\t%.5fz³ + %.5fz² + %.5fz + %.5f',a1,a2,a3,b1+b2+b3,-b1,-b2,-b3);
            end

                % Ausgabe Ausregelschritte und Gesamtregeldauer
                letzter_zeitpunkt = app.AbtastzeitEditField.Value(end);
                if IT2_Strecke == 0
                    app.kEditField.Value = 1;%countervariable;
                    app.TrsEditField.Value = 1;%zeitvariable;
                else
                    app.kEditField.Value =  1;%countervariable;
                    app.TrsEditField.Value = 1;%zeitvariable;
                end

                %Tabelle für U, W, E
                %Wenn Abtastzeit
                %Wenn Sollwert
                %Wenn Keine
                tabellenzeit = Sollwert_korr_u.time;
                values1 = Sollwert_korr_u.signals.values;
                values2 = Sollwert_korr_w.signals.values;
                values3 = Sollwert_korr_e.signals.values;
                Data = table(tabellenzeit, values1, values2, values3);
                uitable_data = table2cell(Data);
                app.MesswerteTable.Data = uitable_data;
                

                % Plot der Stellgröße
                if  app.SollwertkorrekturButton.Value
                    stairs(app.StellAxes, Sollwert_Stellgroesse.time, Sollwert_Stellgroesse.signals.values, "LineWidth", 1.5);

                elseif      app.AbtastzeitButton.Value
                    stairs(app.StellAxes, Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse.time, Abtastzeit_Stellgroesse.signals.values, "LineWidth", 1.5);

                elseif    app.keineButton.Value %für 'keine' wird der Graph für Sollwertkorrektur verwendet
                    stairs(app.StellAxes, Sollwert_Stellgroesse.time, Sollwert_Stellgroesse.signals.values, "LineWidth", 1.5);

                end

                %Plot der Regelgröße
                if  app.SollwertkorrekturButton.Value == 1  
                    plot(app.RegelAxes, Sollwert_Regelgroesse.time, [Sollwert_Regelgroesse.signals.values], "LineWidth", 1.5);

                elseif      app.AbtastzeitButton.Value == 1
                    plot(app.RegelAxes, Abtastzeit_Regelgroesse.time, [Abtastzeit_Regelgroesse.signals.values], "LineWidth", 1.5);

                else        app.keineButton.Value%für 'keine' wird der Graph für Sollwertkorrektur verwendet
                    plot(app.RegelAxes, Sollwert_Regelgroesse.time, [Sollwert_Regelgroesse.signals.values], "LineWidth", 1.5);

                end    

            %% Fehlerausgabe

            if app.AbtastzeitEditField.Value <= 0

                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = 'Abtastzeit muss größer als 0 sein!';
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = 'Abtastzeit muss größer als 0 sein!';
            
            elseif app.U_maxEditField.Value < app.U_minEditField.Value

                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = 'U_max muss größer als U_min sein!';
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = 'U_max muss größer als U_min sein!';

            elseif app.U_maxEditField.Value <= 0
                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = 'U_max muss positiv sein!';
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = 'U_max muss positiv sein!';

            elseif app.U_minEditField.Value > app.U_maxEditField.Value
                
                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = 'U_min muss größer als U_max sein!';
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = 'U_min muss größer als U_max sein!';

            elseif app.U_minEditField.Value >= 0
                app.StreckeTextArea.Value = 'U_min muss negativ sein!';
                app.DeadBeatReglerTextArea.Value = 'U_min muss negativ sein!';
                            
            end



        end

Complete App designer Code:
https://pastebin.com/X6hcpV0i
PID DesignerMod: (only things i added were from line 412 to 442
https://pastebin.com/B3JXxyQj
Simulink code for controller:
Controller 1:
https://pastebin.com/Pk20zNax
Controller 2:
https://pastebin.com/4ap72Jys
I hope someone can find the thing i overlooked or the thing that is missing or wrong.
Tried chatgpt, colleagues, forum articles...
The test function should be :
Zähler: 3
Nenner: 0.1 0.7 1
Transfer Function Gs: 30/((s+5)(s+1)

Okay the Problem mentioned earlier is solved:
Mistake made. I put in :
                assignin('base','b2',b2);
            assignin('base','b1',b2);
            assignin('base','b0',b0);

instead of:
                assignin('base','b2',b2);
            assignin('base','b1',b1);
            assignin('base','b0',b0);


But a new question to why my Simulation runs into an error if u_max or u_min is too big:
https://pastebin.com/bYPg0Bmn
This happens for all values over 4
